# Put a variable in the title of the console (Python)

Tags: python

I would like to put a variable in the title of the console window, but the console crashes as soon as I run this code:

```
import ctypes

for i in range(1500000000):
   ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW("StackOverFlow - HELP -[" + i + "]")
```

Comment: You might be overloading it by changing the title millions of times like that.

Comment: Try putting an `os.sleep()` call in the loop.

Comment: I don't think you can pass a string directly to `SetConsoleTitleW` like that.

Comment: This should work fine if you do it once. Why do you need a near-infinite loop to repeat it? If you need it to stay up to date with the variable value, just do this again each time the value changes. If you have a broader program loop, just run this once in each iteration there. There is no need for such a tight loop here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `i` can only be a string if concatenated with strings. This syntax tells python to try and convert `i` to a string and places it in place of the `%s`.

```py
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW("StackOverFlow - HELP -[%s]" % i)
```

or

```py
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW(f"StackOverFlow - HELP -[{i}]")
```

if you were in python3.6 and above. Or

```py
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW("StackOverFlow - HELP -[{}]".format(i))
```

Kinda breaks the zen of python:

> There should be one—and preferably only one—obvious way to do it.

Comment: Shouldn't that cause the Python script to fail instead of crashing the console?

Comment: Thank you, it's perfect, it can help a lot of people!

Barmar : I just tested and not it works and without any lag.

Comment: @Barmar if run from a _.py_ file an error means the console quits if you have defined any error handling.